# TypeScript, keep type information of initial generic union type

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics, option-type

According to the following code, is it possible to tell TypeScript to check the "origin" type of a generic union type, even the generic is "lost"?

```
const justSymbol: unique symbol = Symbol();
const nothingSymbol: unique symbol = Symbol();

type Just<T> = { [justSymbol]: T };
const just = <T>(x: T): Just<T> => ({ [justSymbol]: x });
const isJust = <T>(x: Maybe<T>): x is Just<T> => (justSymbol in x);

type Nothing = { [nothingSymbol]: null };
const nothing = ({ [nothingSymbol]: null });
const isNothing = <T>(x: Maybe<T>): x is Nothing => (nothingSymbol in x);

/* ... */

type Maybe<T> = Just<T> | Nothing;

const n: Maybe<number> = nothing;
const s: Maybe<string> = nothing;

function forceTsTypeError(x: Maybe<number>): void {}

forceTsTypeError(n); // Correct
forceTsTypeError(s); // Incorrect, but it doesn't matter for TS
```

EDIT:
Added code to turn this into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: TypeScript’s type system is structural, not nominal. If the type parameter is “lost”, then it doesn’t matter.  A value of type `Maybe<string>` which has been narrowed to type `Nothing` by assignment is indeed a value of type `Maybe<number>` and should be accepted as such. If you want to change that you’ll need `Nothing` to be generic and structurally dependent on its type parameter (as I assume `Just<T>` is; you’ve left out the definitions needed for this to be a [mre]). Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write an answer explaining; if not what am I missing?

Comment: Since it's the very same `Nothing` in both cases, why would you care? The compiler inferred `nothing` as `Nothing` and it fits both cases.

Comment: You'd need to add a phantom generic type to `Nothing` for this

Comment: Notice that as soon as you use `let` instead of `const`, they fail as expected

Comment: @jcalz I edited my question to a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Bergi, I changed `const n`and `const s` to `let n`and `let s`, but that doesn't work as well. Is there a tsconfig setting to accomplish this?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for this explanation. You can write this as an answer.

Comment: @christianwuensche Ah probably TypeScript's control flow analysis conflicts with this, as long as it determines that `n`/`s` will be `Nothing` and not an arbitrary `Maybe` at the point where the function is called, the variable type declaration won't help. At best a type assertion (`nothing as Maybe<number>`) would do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252993/discussion-between-christian-wuensche-and-bergi).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/#approach-4-intersection-types-and-brands).

The difference is, that `nothing` is also a function now. So I have to explicitly write `const s = nothing() as Maybe<string>;`

One advantage of this is that `__brand` is only type information and is not included in the output code.

```
const justSymbol: unique symbol = Symbol();
const nothingSymbol: unique symbol = Symbol();

type Just<T> = { [justSymbol]: T };
const just = <T>(x: T): Just<T> => ({ [justSymbol]: x });
const isJust = <T>(x: Maybe<T>): x is Just<T> => (justSymbol in x);

type Nothing<T> = ({ [nothingSymbol]: null } & { __brand: T });
const nothing =<T>() => ({ [nothingSymbol]: null }) as Maybe<T>;
const isNothing = <T>(x: Maybe<T>): x is Nothing<T> => (nothingSymbol in x);

/* ... */

type Maybe<T> = Just<T> | Nothing<T>;

const n = nothing() as Maybe<number>;
const s = nothing() as Maybe<string>;

function forceTsTypeError(x: Maybe<number>): void {}

forceTsTypeError(n); // Correct
forceTsTypeError(s); // Incorrect
----------------^^^
```

Error:

```
Argument of type 'Maybe<string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Maybe<number>'.
Type 'Just<string>' is not assignable to type 'Maybe<number>'.
Type 'Just<string>' is not assignable to type 'Just<number>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: Since you've written up your own answer, should I not bother with mine?  I usually spend quite a bit of time and effort on them so I'd rather not do it if it's not needed anymore.

Comment: @jcalz . I know it is real work to answer questions and explain things to people. You don't have to answer, but I think your answer is also very interesting for others. It helped me a lot. I knew what terms to look for because of your comment. Thank you.